# Llamar una URL con datos Json desde una Api

Tags: json, express, jsonobject, jsonarray

tengo 2 pregunta en las cual pido su apoyo

1.- Estoy trantando de llamar una url con datos JSON de Bloomberg, cuando accedo a ella mediante URL o por Postman obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el meotod en como mando a llamar el api.

```
var bloomberg =
```

`https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/quote/CUR/USDMXN%3ACUR?locale=en/`;

```
app.get("/api/exchange", function(req, res){

    request({
        url: bloomberg, 
        json: false
    }, function(err, resu, body){
        if(!err && resu.statusCode === 200){
            res.send(body);
        }
    })
});
```

Pero cada vez que hago la solicitud desde mi API, obtengo esta ventaja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podria informame, si me hace falta algun Header necesario?

2.- como puedo mandar pedir datos especificos del URL de JSON, por ejemplo quiero solamente mostrar los datos de "Hihg Price", "Low Price" y "Price"

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Podrías indicar que librería utilizas para esa función `request` en tu API?

Comment: var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var useragent = require("express-useragent");

soy totalmente nuevo en este ambiente, esos son los requiere que tengo.

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado el problema del captchas, solo se debia poner este header

 headers: {
         'User-Agent':'PostmanRuntime/7.17.1',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Postman-Token': 'f8af99b5-febd-4ec0-a31f-44a042b6c03f'
       },

Comment: Me pregunto por qué tienes ese parámetro `{json: false}` en tu request, sirve también si lo quitas?

Comment: No de hecho no sirve para nada, si lo tengo o lo quito, ya que como estoy indicando que la solicutd es una aplicacion/json en la cabecera, ya no sirve de mucho

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo la segunda pregunta, pero si deseas acceder los datos que vienen en el json puedes usar la notación del punto. Por ejemplo:

```
myJson.highPrice
```

Por otra parte, si quieres que la api devuelva un conjunto especifico de datos; es mas complicado y deberas modificar la api.

Comment: La url, viene completamente con esos datos, no puedo modificar ni el orden que peticion, solamente queria saber si podia pedirle al URL que solo me diera lo que necesito.

Comment: Lamentablemente, la arquitectura rest no suele funcionar de esa forma. Lo que comentas es posible actualmente con GraphQL